# How to properly typeset the set of all equivalence classes

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    X/\sim
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which produces
[image]

Not very appealing to the eye. Is there a way to reduce the space between `\sim` and `/`. Furthermore, what would be the correct way of typesetting this and in general which symbol should be used for typesetting an equivalence relation?

Comment: `\sim` is a binary relation and as such has additional spacing before and after the symbol

Comment: `X/{\sim}`; there should already be something like this on the site.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Did not found something at first sight. Maybe I was looking for something too math involved.

Comment: i think this could count as a duplicate: [Is there a way to make a symbol behave as either mathord or mathrel depending on context?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276760/579).  (granted the title isn't promising.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to use logical markup for such typesetting if this is needed a lot of times, say, using a command `\equivclass`

It is possible to introduce some negative spacing with `\!`, but this will lead to very narrow spacing between the `/` and `~` symbols. I don't recommend it. Judge yourself, however.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand{\equivclass}[1]{%
  #1/{\sim}%
}
\newcommand{\equivcls}[1]{%
  #1/\!{\sim}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\equivclass{X}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\equivcls{X}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]